# Getting Contents of `resource_uri` During Tastypie Hydrate

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

How can I resolve a `resource_uri` during a Tastypie `hydrate` call?

I am passing the following data object to a Tastypie resource:

```
{
  'date': u'2013-10-31 15:06',
  'visitor': u'/visitorlog/api/v1/person/33/',
  'purpose': u'Testing'
}
```

I would like to take the `visitor` and pull the entire record in a `hydrate` function, which populates a field with some extra information.

I am currently doing this by splitting out the `id` and performing a search:

```
def hydrate_meta(self, bundle):
    '''
    This will populate the `meta` field with a snapshot of the employee record, if the `empid` is set.  This is done so if the employee record changes we retain certain information at the time of the visit.
    '''

    split_id = bundle.data['visitor'].split('/')
    # the id of `visitor` is in `split_id[-2]

    # get the record of this visitor from the Django model
    person_record = Person.objects.get(pk = split_id[-2])

    # ... snipped ... create the `meta_value` object

    bundle.data['meta'] = meta_values

    return bundle
```

This is working, but calling `split` on the `resource_uri` does not seem the most elegant way to do this.

Is there more effective way to pull a record given a `resource_uri`?

Answer (score 0):

`Resource.get_via_uri(url)` ([doc](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.16/tastypie/resources.py#L816)) might come in handy.